# Python Selenium Firefox Geckodriver exited

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to start Firefox using selenium webdriver. This is my code (got it from https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-firefox/)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://dev.to")

driver.find_element_by_id("nav-search").send_keys("Selenium")
```

However when I try to run this code in Visual Studio Code it gives me following error instead of running firefox:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/surf/Desktop/aq.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/surf/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/surf/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/surf/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6
```

I was searching in google for the Status code -6 for about 1 hours but couldn't find something helpful.

Can you please tell me why I'm getting this error and how I can get rid of it?

Btw. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS as OS (Linux Surf 5.15.0-48-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 26 13:26:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)